# Selenium: How to avoid StaleElementReferenceException when looping through a set of elements?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a page that contains a bunch of tables.  I loop through the tables in the outer loop and then loop through each row in the table in the inner loop.  It all works fine.  But some of the pages have a Next button. When I add code to click that after completing the page, then I start getting StaleElementReferenceException while looping through the rows of a table.

Here is the code:

```java
WebDriverWait wait1 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
WebElement maxPage = null;
WebElement auctionsWaitingDiv = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='Head_W']"));
if (auctionsWaitingDiv.isDisplayed() == false) return properties;

try {
    maxPage = wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("maxWA")));
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    return properties;
}

Integer maxPageNo = 1;
if (!maxPage.getText().isEmpty()) 
    maxPageNo = Integer.parseInt(maxPage.getText());
for (int i = 1; i <= maxPageNo; i++) {
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='Area_W']"));    //only look at Auctions Waiting section
    WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
    List<WebElement> tables = null;
    try {
        tables = wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("table[class='ad_tab']")));
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        System.out.println("table not found in allotted time");
        return properties;
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
        System.out.println("returning due to StaleElementReferenceException");
        return properties;

    }
    for (WebElement table: tables) {  
        List<String> propAttributes = new ArrayList<>();

        // StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference of
        // <table class="ad_tab"> is stale; either the element is no
        // longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current
        // frame context, or the document has been refreshed
        List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr"));

        String parcelLink = "";
        for (WebElement row : rows) { 
            WebElement key = row.findElement(By.cssSelector("th"));
            WebElement val = row.findElement(By.cssSelector("td"));
            String keyVal = key.getText() + val.getText();
            propAttributes.add(keyVal);
            if (key.getText().equals("Parcel ID:")) {
                WebElement a = val.findElement(By.cssSelector("a"));
                parcelLink = a.getAttribute("href");
            }
        }
    }
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='PageRight']")).click();  //click the "Next" button
}
```

What I don't understand is why the stale element is happening at all?  The page is not changing during the loop and I've waited until all elements have been fetched.  How to avoid the StaleElementReferenceException?

Edit: The last stack trace shows it is happening in this line:

```
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.cssSelector("tr"));
```

and the error message above it shows:

> SEVERE: null
>
> org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: The element reference of `<table class="ad_tab">` is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Comment: Can you post the stack trace or identify which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Just edited my post to include it.

Comment: As you scroll down the page, do some of these tables appear and disappear?

Comment: no, I don't see that happening.  Here is a link to the page I'm currently looking at: https://brevard.realforeclose.com/index.cfm?zaction=AUCTION&Zmethod=PREVIEW&AUCTIONDATE=08/22/2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after tearing my hair out for a day, I finally realized what was happening.  It should have been obvious to me.  When the "Next" button is clicked, it takes some time for the new page to load.  By simply adding a delay, the new DOM is loaded and processing begins on it, not again on the previous one!

```
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@class='PageRight']")).click();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000); //provide some time for the page to load before processing it
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RealAuction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Now it runs to completion with no StaleElementReferenceException.

Comment: You should use WebDriverWait instead. Just wait until the element is visible or clickable. Thread.sleep might not be stable enough. On one side it can make you tests slower than required on the other side waiting 4 seconds might not be enough.

Comment: The problem is that the new page has the same element identifiers as the previous page so WebDriverWait thinks  it's already there when really the dom still contains the old page.

Answer (score 2):

The [StaleElementReferenceException](https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp) is thrown whenever you want to access an element reference which is not available anymore. This happens when the element is no longer attached to the DOM or if the page was updated.

The solution for this is just searching for the element again whenever this happens.
You could adapt all your tests or page objects. Or you write your own RobustWebDriver and RobustWebElement which refreshes the element if a SERE is thrown.

RobustWebDriver:

```
public class RobustWebDriver implements WebDriver {

    private WebDriver originalWebDriver;

    public RobustWebDriver(WebDriver webDriver) {
        this.originalWebDriver = webDriver;
    }

    @Override
    public void get(String url) {
        this.originalWebDriver.get(url);
    }

    @Override
    public String getCurrentUrl() {
        return this.originalWebDriver.getCurrentUrl();
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.originalWebDriver.getTitle();
    }

    @Override
    public List<WebElement> findElements(By by) {
        List<WebElement> elements = new ArrayList<>();
        for (WebElement element : this.originalWebDriver.findElements(by)) {
            elements.add(new RobustWebElement(element, by, this));
        }
        return elements;
    }

    @Override
    public WebElement findElement(By by) {
        return new RobustWebElement(this.originalWebDriver.findElement(by), by, this);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageSource() {
        return this.originalWebDriver.getPageSource();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.originalWebDriver.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void quit() {
        this.originalWebDriver.quit();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getWindowHandles() {
        return this.originalWebDriver.getWindowHandles();
    }

    @Override
    public String getWindowHandle() {
        return this.originalWebDriver.getWindowHandle();
    }

    @Override
    public TargetLocator switchTo() {
        return this.originalWebDriver.switchTo();
    }

    @Override
    public Navigation navigate() {
        return this.originalWebDriver.navigate();
    }

    @Override
    public Options manage() {
        return this.originalWebDriver.manage();
    }
}
```

RobustWebElement:

```
public class RobustWebElement implements WebElement {

    private WebElement originalElement;
    private RobustWebDriver driver;
    private By by;
    private static final int MAX_RETRIES = 10;

    public RobustWebElement(WebElement element, By by, RobustWebDriver driver) {
        this.originalElement = element;
        this.by = by;
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @Override
    public void click() {
        int retries = 0;
        while (retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
            try {
                this.originalElement.click();
                return;
            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
                refreshElement();
            }
            retries++;
        }
        throw new StaleElementReferenceException(
                String.format("Element is still stale after %s retries.", MAX_RETRIES));
    }

    @Override
    public void sendKeys(CharSequence... keysToSend) {
        int retries = 0;
        while (retries < MAX_RETRIES) {
            try {
                this.originalElement.sendKeys(keysToSend);
                return;
            } catch (StaleElementReferenceException ex) {
                refreshElement();
            }
            retries++;
        }
        throw new StaleElementReferenceException(
                String.format("Element is still stale after %s retries.", MAX_RETRIES));
    }

    // TODO add other unimplemented methods with similar logic.

    private void refreshElement() {
        this.originalElement = driver.findElement(by);
    }
```

And then you just need to wrap your WebDriver into the RobustWebDriver and you are ready to go:

```
WebDriver driver = new RobustWebDriver(new ChromeDriver());
```

**EDIT:**

Of course you need to take care of scrolling up and down by yourself.

Comment: +1. Very similar to a question I answered just a week or two ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225358/3092298 except this was solving problems with waiting for an element to appear. This answer coupled with mine would guard against both problems.

Comment: Nice, just had a look at it. I think we could come up with the UltimateWebDriver which handles even more. Scrolling, waiting, SERE handling, ...
Will think about introducing something like that into my testframework to help my colleagues even more.

Comment: But if I understand, would work only for a single WebElement, not a list of them?

Comment: Let me be more specific.  If you are in the middle of a list of tables or a list of rows, how do you re-find the table or row you were on before it went stale?

Comment: As you can see in the constructor we are saving the `By` for each element. If the element is accessed and a **SERE** is thrown we are using the By to find it again. It does not matter if this is a list of elements or a single element because we are overriding the `findElement` and `findElements` method. Each element takes care to refresh itself if needed.