# What is the best way to use Page Object Model with Page Fatcory

Tags: java, maven, selenium, frameworks

I am currently have a task assigned to create a Automation framework in Java and I had an argument with the architect on the test design. Below is how my current framework look like, thie Maven, POM and PageFactory.

**Project** 
 - **Utlities Package** - contains all the utilities classes 
 - **Locators** - contains only WebElements of the website (Page Factory) 
 - **Actions** - contains click, sendkeys and other actions for the Locators 
 - **Step** - Calling and asserting the Action class method (cucumber step definition) 
 - **Custome Listeners** - Listener class

The architect advised me to remove the actions class and add all the actions within the locator class itself and this will avoid additional class creation for every locator class. But what I had in mind is as the project go bigger this will just look messier. So I tried to seperate locators as a different class and actions on it in a different class. So wanted to ask what is the best approach, adding actions in the locator class or seperating ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Page object model, where you can assign your all web locators in to single file. There should be different class as according to different Scenario, different Web Pages or Customized utilities as you defined(if any).

You can use Page Object model by two approach:-

-Simple defining: (There are many provisions where you can implement such things without having reference of WebElement, and directly using By reference. So assigning value on Web element not required at all.)

```
By demo_get_text=By.className("xyz");
```

-With Page Factory: (It executes faster from above)

```
@FindBy(className="xyz")  WebElement demo_get_text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is better. All common actions should be under one class and every page object class should extend it. By doing so, this will make your tests more robust and stops the Page classes from being polluted with driver implementation details.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an opinionated question I would recommend to use the approach of your software architect and remove the Action classes. I am not sure whats the intention for the Step classes, so I would remove them as well.

- Project

  - Utilities
  - PageObjects
  - CustomListeners
  - WebDriver

You can create a BasePageObject which contains all common locators and methods e.g. handling some navbar or menu. This class should then be extended by all other page objects.

Additionally to that, I would recommend to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57513438/7450414) answer. It shows how you can wrap the RemoteWebDriver to make it more robust which will be helpful when implementing UI tests.