# Selenium StaleElementReferenceException when the element refreshes every second

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my web application there is a set of progress bars that update every second. When I look at the DOM in Chrome dev tools I can see that the elements are getting destroyed and recreated. So when I try to read the value or the text on a given label I get a StaleElementReferenceException.

[Screenshot of Elements in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYxlX.png)

A specific example is I'm trying to get the value from the title attribute of this element. But I keep getting the error when running this line of code.

```
var progressBarCompletion = flyoutRow.JobProgressBar.GetAttribute("title");
```

Full error message: *OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document*

Comment: If `flyoutRow` is also a `WebElement` then that could also be stale, not just `JobProgressBar`. You might be better off trying to find `JobProgressBar` on its own rather than as a child of `flyoutRow`. Can you post the code that you are using for `flyoutRow.JobProgressBar` as well? It's hard to tell exactly what is throwing the error without additional context of your code.

Comment: screenshot of html code is bad practice, for debugging your problem no one will write it for you, its kind of help to help yourself. Welcome to SO! please read [mcve] and follow same in the next posts

Comment: Take a look at this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57513438/7450414
I think you can build something similar in C# and your StaleElementReferenceExceptions should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Without full context of your HTML, it's a bit difficult to write a fully-working sample, but I have an idea about how you can avoid the `StaleElementException` and still run your code to retrieve `title` as intended.

We can attempt to get `title` attribute in a loop, where we `try` / `catch` the `StaleElementException`, and hopefully still return a value for `title` as well:

```
public string GetProgressBarTitle()
{
    var currentAttempts = 0; // track number of attempts

    // find the element for the first time
    var progressBarCompletion = driver.Findlement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'progressJobProgressBar')]")); // this probably needs to be more specific to your row 

    // attempt to retrieve title, in a loop:

    while (currentAttempts <= 5) // attempt to find the title up to 5 times
    {
        // try to get title...
        try
        {
            var title = progressBarCompletion.GetAttribute("title");
            return title;
        }
        catch (StaleElementReferenceException)
        {
            // if element is stale, find it again & retry
            progressBarCompletion = driver.Findlement(By.XPath("//div[contains(@class, 'progressJobProgressBar')]"));
            currentAttempts++; // increment number of attempts
        }
    } // end while
    return string.Empty; // handle case where number of attempts passed & title was not returned
} // end method
```

The above code will attempt to perform `GetAttribute("title");` in a loop, catching the `StaleElementReferenceException` and fetching a new copy of `progressBarCompletion` element in the event that it has gone stale. The loop will attempt up to 5 times before quitting. You can change the number of attempts as needed.

Hopefully this can get you started. The XPath selector I chose might not be specific enough here -- I can see that each progress bar must be a child of `flyoutRow`.

An alternative XPath for `progressBarCompletion` could be:

```
//li[div[text()='Zipping']]/div[contains(@class, 'progressJobProgressBar')]
```

which will grab the progress bar element with job description 'Zipping'. This may be a little closer to what you are looking for.

Comment: I think you may have meant to initialize `currentAttempts` to 0

Comment: Corrected, thank you. I was originally using `maxAttempts` as a variable, but changed it to `currentAttempts` after the fact.